# Clean this Code: Initializing variables in a list

Tags: python, list, initialization

I have a .csv file with a bunch of dollar values. Call it:

```
value1,value2,value3
$1,000,$2,000,$3,000
```

I'm trying to run through this spreadsheet, removing the '$'s.

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
file = pd.read_csv('theFile.csv')

value1, value2, value3 = 0,0,0
variables = [value1, value2, value3]

for i,j in zip(variables, file.columns[1:]):
    i = float(file[j].iloc[-1].replace('$','')
```

This just feels wrong to me. And doesn't work. It's updating the list's items, but not the variables themselves. I could have sworn there was a way to do this without resorting to a dict.

I'm just trying to initiate the variables in that `for-loop` declaration, itself. At the very least, I'd like the loop to update the values of the prior values so I can perform math with them instead of the elements of a list that represents them. Nothing I try seems to work. How do I initiate a list of variables in the same line they're declared, while still assigning them to a list for me to loop through?

Also, please let me know if this isn't the place to be asking for how to make my code more elegant. I've been trying to find what is, and it keeps bringing me here.

Comment: "It's updating the list's items, but not the variables themselves." of course not, nowhere do you update them. Note, it isn't even updating the list values...

Comment: It looks like you are trying to dynamically create/modify variables. *Don't do that*. Use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`.

Comment: @juanpra.arrivillaga Yeah, that's my issue. I can make this code work just fine calling each variable one-by-one, but that's so many lines of the same thing. 
I'm trying to find a way updates the separate values, but iterating through them like a list.

I was thinking some form of function calling, but it's just... beyond me, right now.

Answer (score 0):

I FIGURED IT OUT!

Anyone please comment how to better ways to put this to words, but:
If I want to assign values to a group of independent values, I want the following format:

```
value1, value2, value3 = [doTheThing(each) for each in file.iloc[-1]]
```

I don't know the proper terminology for what's being done, here, so if someone could comment for me to update, or even make a new answer with the proper terminology, it'd help educate me a great deal!